# Clearing textbox and hiddenfield

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In source code of asp i'm using onClick() in textbox i.e

```
onClick="openpopup('ct100$contentPlaceHolder$hdpackageid',
           'ct100$contentPlaceHolder$txtpackageid','package')"
```

for opening a popup containing package details.and in its selection in popup packageid is stored into a hiddenfield and packagename is stored into textbox. I need to clear the hidden field and textbox after selection, if I do not need it. I use "this.blur();" for not editing the text box. I need these things to be write in vb code,means in onClick I want to clear textbox, hiddenfield and then call popup. Can anyone help me to solve the problem. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Can you please be more clear and format you question?

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick = 'document.getElementById("textbox").value = ""; openpopup(........); '
```